# 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I fix my run-time error in the code below?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import zipfile
def extract(zipf, pwd):
    try:
        zipf.extractall(psw=(pwd))
        return
    except :
        return
def main():
    zipf = zipfile.is_zipfile("dave.zip")
    pwdfile=open("pwdlist.txt", "r")
    for line in pwdfile.readlines():
        psw = line.strip()("\n")
        guess = extract(zipf, psw)
        if guess:
            print ("[+] Password is : %s"%(psw) + ("\n"))
            exit(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

> psw = line.strip()("\n") TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Did you mean `psw = line.strip("\n")`?

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
psw = line.strip()("\n")
```

To

```
psw = line.strip("\n")
```

Note, `line.strip()` **returns a string** which you then try to call, so it's something like:

```
>>> "I'm a string"()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```
>>> string_object = "I'm a string"
>>> string_object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.split()` is a function call that returns a string.  You then tried to call that string *as a function* with an argument of "\n".

If you're trying to split on line breaks, you need

```
line.split("\n")
```

Comment: _"If you're trying to split on line breaks, you need `line.strip("\n")`"_ - Or `line.splitlines()` would work to. You an also use `str.splitlines` to save the newline characters if needed. Just a side note.

Comment: strip == remove smth from begin/end of string, split = make a list of strings out of one string  - Your answer confuses me.

Comment: Oh ... duh ... fingers doing the wrong stuff ... thanks.  Answer edited.  The person who up-voted must have been reading my mind, rather than the original text.